# How to perform SCD 1 on snwoflake tables using talend

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend, snowflake-schema, talend-mdm

I am quite new to Talend and I need to perform the scd1 operation on snwoflake tables. Can anyone suggest me the important components I need to use in talend to perform this operation. I tried with tDBSCD but it does not allow snowflake database. Is there is any workaround to perform the task. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Source Component-->TMap-->Snowflake output Component.

Connect to your normal source and add another source which should be your snowflake target table as a lookup and in TMap you need to join both based on the business key in the TMAP add the variable the SCD columns calculation and add the two targets outputs one for insert and one for the update, In the update link of the snowflake keep the key column and the add merge in the type. And play the job.